# Django site hosted in openshift not serving static files

Tags: python, django, openshift, django-1.7

I have hosted a Django 1.7 site in openshift but it is showing 404 error accessing static files like css/js/img i.e it is not serving static files.
This is the url to my site http://by120in-pnikhilvarma.rhcloud.com/ 
This is my settings.py code

"""

```
Django settings for by120 project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<secret>'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog',
    'cart',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'by120.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'by120.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATIC_PATH, )
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (TEMPLATE_PATH,)

SITE_NAME = 'By120'
META_KEYWORDS = 'Tee-shirts, Fashion, Design, Custom'
META_DISCRIPTION = 'By120 is a online fashion store for out of the box tee-shirt designs. Our designs make you look cool and compleate'
```

And my url.py code is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'products.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^s/$', 'products.views.search', name='search'),
    url(r'^products/$', 'products.views.all', name='products'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'products.views.single', name='single_product'),
    url(r'^cart/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'carts.views.remove_from_cart', name='remove_from_cart'),
    url(r'^cart/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'carts.views.add_to_cart', name='add_to_cart'),
    url(r'^cart/$', 'carts.views.view', name='cart'),
    url(r'^checkout/$', 'orders.views.checkout', name='checkout'),
    url(r'^orders/$', 'orders.views.orders', name='user_orders'),
    url(r'^ajax/dismiss_marketing_message/$', 'marketing.views.dismiss_marketing_message', name='dismiss_marketing_message'),
    url(r'^ajax/email_signup/$', 'marketing.views.email_signup', name='ajax_email_signup'),
    url(r'^ajax/add_user_address/$', 'accounts.views.add_user_address', name='ajax_add_user_address'),

    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    #(?P<all_items>.*)
    #(?P<id>\d+)
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'accounts.views.logout_view', name='auth_logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'accounts.views.login_register_view', name='auth_login'),
    #url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'accounts.views.registration_view', name='auth_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/address/add/$', 'accounts.views.add_user_address', name='add_user_address'),
    url(r'^accounts/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$', 'accounts.views.activation_view', name='activation_view'),
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: So you’re running with `DEBUG = True` in production and are publicly providing your `SECRET_KEY`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `python manage.py collectstatic` - worked for me once in this kind of situation.

Comment: Might not be the solution since there is `DEBUG = True` in settings.py